# Errors with Google Protocol Buffers

Tags: c++, visual-studio, protocol-buffers, msvc12

So I opened the protobuf.sln file in Visual Studio 2012 and clicked on Build Solution (It is under release mode). The errors I get are:

```
7>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(347,5): error MSB6003: The specified task executable "CL.exe" could not be run. The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Kels\protobuf-2.6.0\vsprojects\Release\cl.write.1.tlog' because it is being used by another process.

9>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(172,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 3.

8>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(172,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 3.
```

In the instructions from google protocol buffers it says:

> To avoid conflicts between the MSVC debug and release runtime
>   libraries, when compiling a debug build of your application, you may
>   need to link against a debug build of libprotobuf.lib.  Similarly,
>   release builds should link against release libs.

Is this causing the problem? If so, how to I link against a debug build of libprotobuf.lib?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**
This is my output now. With errors. Still having this problem!

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: libprotobuf, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: gtest, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
3>------ Rebuild All started: Project: libprotobuf-lite, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
2>  gtest-all.cc
3>  stringprintf.cc
1>  stringprintf.cc
3>  zero_copy_stream_impl_lite.cc
1>  zero_copy_stream_impl_lite.cc
1>  zero_copy_stream_impl.cc
3>  zero_copy_stream.cc
3>  wire_format_lite.cc
1>  zero_copy_stream.cc
1>  wire_format_lite.cc
3>  repeated_field.cc
1>  wire_format.cc
3>  atomicops_internals_x86_msvc.cc
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(1299,5): warning MSB8012: TargetPath(C:\Users\Kels\protobuf-2.6.1\gtest\msvc\protobuf/Debug\gtest.lib) does not match the Library's OutputFile property value (C:\Users\Kels\protobuf-2.6.1\gtest\msvc\protobuf\Debug\gtestd.lib). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Lib.OutputFile).
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(1301,5): warning MSB8012: TargetName(gtest) does not match the Library's OutputFile property value (gtestd). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Lib.OutputFile).
2>  gtest.vcxproj -> C:\Users\Kels\protobuf-2.6.1\gtest\msvc\protobuf/Debug\gtest.lib
4>------ Rebuild All started: Project: gtest_main, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
4>  gtest_main.cc
1>  unknown_field_set.cc
3>  once.cc
1>  tokenizer.cc
1>  text_format.cc
4>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(1299,5): warning MSB8012: TargetPath(C:\Users\Kels\protobuf-2.6.1\gtest\msvc\protobuf/Debug\gtest_main.lib) does not match the Library's OutputFile property value (C:\Users\Kels\protobuf-2.6.1\gtest\msvc\protobuf\Debug\gtest_maind.lib). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Lib.OutputFile).
4>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(1301,5): warning MSB8012: TargetName(gtest_main) does not match the Library's OutputFile property value (gtest_maind). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Lib.OutputFile).
3>  message_lite.cc
4>  gtest_main.vcxproj -> C:\Users\Kels\protobuf-2.6.1\gtest\msvc\protobuf/Debug\gtest_main.lib
3>  generated_message_util.cc
1>  substitute.cc
3>  extension_set.cc
1>  strutil.cc
3>  common.cc
1>  structurally_valid.cc
1>  service.cc
3>  coded_stream.cc
1>  repeated_field.cc
3>  Generating Code...
3>c:\users\kels\protobuf-2.6.1\src\google\protobuf\extension_set.cc(74): warning C4715: 'google::protobuf::internal::`anonymous namespace'::is_packable' : not all control paths return a value
1>  reflection_ops.cc
3>coded_stream.obj : warning LNK4075: ignoring '/EDITANDCONTINUE' due to '/OPT:ICF' specification
3>     Creating library Debug\libprotobuf-lite.lib and object Debug\libprotobuf-lite.exp
3>  libprotobuf-lite.vcxproj -> C:\Users\Kels\protobuf-2.6.1\vsprojects\Debug\libprotobuf-lite.dll
1>  printer.cc
1>  parser.cc
1>  atomicops_internals_x86_msvc.cc
1>  once.cc
1>  message_lite.cc
1>  Generating Code...
1>  Compiling...
1>  message.cc
1>  importer.cc
1>  strtod.cc
1>  gzip_stream.cc
1>  generated_message_util.cc
1>  generated_message_reflection.cc
1>  extension_set_heavy.cc
1>  extension_set.cc
1>  dynamic_message.cc
1>  descriptor_database.cc
1>  descriptor.pb.cc
1>  descriptor.cc
1>  common.cc
1>  coded_stream.cc
1>  Generating Code...
1>c:\users\kels\protobuf-2.6.1\src\google\protobuf\extension_set.cc(74): warning C4715: 'google::protobuf::internal::`anonymous namespace'::is_packable' : not all control paths return a value
1>coded_stream.obj : warning LNK4075: ignoring '/EDITANDCONTINUE' due to '/OPT:ICF' specification
1>     Creating library Debug\libprotobuf.lib and object Debug\libprotobuf.exp
1>  libprotobuf.vcxproj -> C:\Users\Kels\protobuf-2.6.1\vsprojects\Debug\libprotobuf.dll
5>------ Rebuild All started: Project: libprotoc, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
5>  python_generator.cc
5>  java_string_field.cc
5>  java_shared_code_generator.cc
5>  java_service.cc
5>  java_primitive_field.cc
5>  java_name_resolver.cc
5>  java_message_field.cc
5>  java_message.cc
5>  java_lazy_message_field.cc
5>  java_helpers.cc
5>  java_generator_factory.cc
5>  java_generator.cc
5>  java_file.cc
5>  java_field.cc
5>  java_extension.cc
5>  java_enum_field.cc
5>  java_enum.cc
5>  java_context.cc
5>  cpp_string_field.cc
5>  cpp_service.cc
5>  Generating Code...
5>  Compiling...
5>  cpp_primitive_field.cc
5>  cpp_message_field.cc
5>  cpp_message.cc
5>c:\users\kels\protobuf-2.6.1\src\google\protobuf\compiler\cpp\cpp_message.cc(692): warning C4065: switch statement contains 'default' but no 'case' labels
5>  cpp_helpers.cc
5>  cpp_generator.cc
5>  cpp_file.cc
5>  cpp_field.cc
5>  cpp_extension.cc
5>  cpp_enum_field.cc
5>  cpp_enum.cc
5>  plugin.pb.cc
5>  plugin.cc
5>  zip_writer.cc
5>  subprocess.cc
5>  command_line_interface.cc
5>  code_generator.cc
5>  java_doc_comment.cc
5>  Generating Code...
5>java_doc_comment.obj : warning LNK4075: ignoring '/EDITANDCONTINUE' due to '/OPT:ICF' specification
5>LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'C:\Users\Kels\protobuf-2.6.1\vsprojects\Debug\libprotobuf.lib'
6>------ Rebuild All started: Project: protoc, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
7>------ Rebuild All started: Project: test_plugin, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
7>  file.cc
6>  main.cc
6>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Users\Kels\protobuf-2.6.1\vsprojects\Debug\libprotobuf.lib'
8>------ Rebuild All started: Project: lite-test, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
8>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppClean.targets(75,5): warning : The process cannot access the file 'C:\USERS\KELS\PROTOBUF-2.6.1\VSPROJECTS\DEBUG\VC110.PDB' because it is being used by another process.
8>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppClean.targets(75,5): warning : The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Kels\protobuf-2.6.1\vsprojects\Debug\vc110.idb' because it is being used by another process.
8>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppClean.targets(75,5): warning : The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Kels\protobuf-2.6.1\vsprojects\Debug\vc110.pdb' because it is being used by another process.
7>  mock_code_generator.cc
8>  Generating unittest_lite.pb.{h,cc}...
8>  The system cannot find the path specified.
8>  Generating unittest_import_lite.pb.{h,cc}...
8>  The system cannot find the path specified.
8>  Generating unittest_import_public_lite.pb.{h,cc}...
8>  The system cannot find the path specified.
8>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(172,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 3.
7>  test_plugin.cc
7>  Generating Code...
7>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Users\Kels\protobuf-2.6.1\vsprojects\Debug\libprotobuf.lib'
9>------ Rebuild All started: Project: tests, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
9>  Generating cpp_test_bad_identifiers.pb.{h,cc}...
9>  The system cannot find the path specified.
9>  Generating unittest.pb.{h,cc}...
9>  The system cannot find the path specified.
9>  Generating unittest_custom_options.pb.{h,cc}...
9>  The system cannot find the path specified.
9>  Generating unittest_embed_optimize_for.pb.{h,cc}...
9>  The system cannot find the path specified.
9>  Generating unittest_import.pb.{h,cc}...
9>  The system cannot find the path specified.
9>  Generating unittest_import_public.pb.{h,cc}...
9>  The system cannot find the path specified.
9>  Generating unittest_lite_imports_nonlite.pb.{h,cc}...
9>  The system cannot find the path specified.
9>  Generating unittest_mset.pb.{h,cc}...
9>  The system cannot find the path specified.
9>  Generating unittest_optimize_for.pb.{h,cc}...
9>  The system cannot find the path specified.
9>  Generating unittest_no_generic_services.pb.{h,cc}...
9>  The system cannot find the path specified.
9>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(172,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 3.
========== Rebuild All: 4 succeeded, 5 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: The errors says "The specified task executable "CL.exe" could not be run. The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Kels\protobuf-2.6.0\vsprojects\Release\cl.write.1.tlog' because it is being used by another process.". This can't be caused by incorrect lib configuration. Check the access to that file. Someone is holding a lock on it.

Comment: Closed a window that was viewing it and that solved that error. The other two are still there after a Build again.